# Using mssql and node-sql to UPDATE

Tags: mysql, node.js, node-sqlserver

I'm using [mssql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql) together with [node-sql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sql) to build `SELECT` queries but I can't find any example how to use it to build UPDATE queries. I have an object where properties corresponds to table fields and I would like to update all of them.

Assume:

```
child: sql.define({
    name: 'children',
    columns: ['id', 'name', 'surname', 'group']
  })
```

and:

```
var data = {/*new child data*/};

var query = child.update(data).where(child.id.equals(data.id)).toQuery().text;
```

How can I use this with `mssql` without knowing values and count of `data` properties?

Right now I have this:

```
connection.query(query, [data.id, data.name, data.surname, data.group], function(err, result) {

      res.redirect('/index');
    });
```

that can be achieved by using lodash's `values`:

```
_.values(data);
```

which returns array of object properties but it does not guarantee correct order which is deal breaker.

How can I tackle that problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will return an array of values based on the order of table columns:

```
child.columns.map(function(col){return data[col.name]})
```

It might be possible to compact the above in shorter form with lodash.

Comment: `child.columns.map(function(col){return data[col.name]})` did  the trick

Answer (score 0):

Few days later I figured node-sql's query object also has .values property besides .text property so above update can be written as

```
var data = {/*new child data*/};

var query = child.update(data).where(child.id.equals(data.id)).toQuery();

connection.query(query.text, query.values, function(err, result) {

  res.redirect('/index');
});
```